# How to initialize the Monetization SDK before accessing any classes or members of the Advertisements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have video ad which connected to loosing panel on game scene which shows when player loose. I also need banner ad on bottom of my scene which will always shows when player is playing.

Becouse banner is part of the Advertisements API, I need to use Monetization for video ad and Advertisements for banner, but I'm getting error with: "An item with the same key has already been added". So I initialize the Monetization SDK before Advertisements API on main script as unity site told me, but still getting this error.

Main script:

```
using UnityEngine.Monetization;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

private void Start() {
        Monetization.Initialize("1234567", true);
        Advertisement.Initialize("1234567");
        StartCoroutine(ShowBannerWhenReady());
}

IEnumerator ShowBannerWhenReady() {
        while (!Advertisement.IsReady("Banner")) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }
        Advertisement.Banner.Show("Banner");
}
```

Loose script:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Monetization;

private void Start() {
        if (Monetization.isSupported) {
            Monetization.Initialize("1234567", true);
        }
}

if (gameObject.name == "Free") {
            if (cube.GetComponent<NewScpr>().sec_lf == 0) {
                if (Monetization.IsReady("rewardedVideo")) {
                    ShowAdCallbacks options = new ShowAdCallbacks();
                    options.finishCallback = HandleShowResult;
                    ShowAdPlacementContent ads = Monetization.GetPlacementContent("rewardedVideo") as ShowAdPlacementContent;
                    ads.Show(options);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Maybe Monetization and Advertisement share a list of Elements, and adding the same key twice is not allowed? What do the examples do in regards to the key?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to remove the **UnityEngine.Monetization** namespace.

> **Advertisements Namespace**
>
> > • Works with all versions of Unity after version 4.6
> >
> > • Can show video, display, and playable ads (rewarded and
> >     non-rewarded)
> >
> > • Can show IAP Promo ads (requires Unity IAP) (added in version 2.3)
> >
> > • Supports Personalized Placements (requires Unity IAP) (added in
> >     version 2.3)
> >
> > • Can show banner ads (added in version 3.0)
>
> **Monetization Namespace**
>
> > • Works with all versions of Unity after version 5.0.1
> >
> > • Can show video, display, and playable ads (rewarded and
> >     non-rewarded)
> >
> > • Can show IAP Promo ads (with any IAP solution)
> >
> > • Can show Native IAP Promo (with any IAP solution)
> >
> > • Supports Personalized Placements (with any IAP solution)
> >
> > • Can show AR ads

Here is how I added both banner and video just with **UnityEngine.Advertisements** and it works just fine.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class UnityAds : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{
    private Button rewardableAdButton;

    public const string GameId = "YourGameID";
    public const bool TestMode = true; // Change this to false when going live

    private readonly string bannerPlacementId = "YourBannerPlacementId";
    private readonly string rewardVideoPlacementId = "YourVideoPlacementId";

    void Awake()
    {
        rewardableAdButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("RewardableAd").GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (rewardableAdButton)
        {
            rewardableAdButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowRewardedVideo);
        }

        Advertisement.AddListener(this);

        if (Advertisement.isSupported && !Advertisement.isInitialized)
        {
            Advertisement.Initialize(GameId, TestMode);
        }

        Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        StartCoroutine(ShowBannerWhenReady());

    }

    #region ####### REWARDABLE AD ##########

    void ShowRewardedVideo()
    {
        Advertisement.Show(rewardVideoPlacementId);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId)
    {
         rewardableAdButton.interactable = Advertisement.IsReady(rewardVideoPlacementId);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad started");
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error while playing Ad");
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ad is finished, reward the player");
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
        {
            Debug.Log("User skipped, do not reward the player");
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ########## BANNER ##########

    public IEnumerator ShowBannerWhenReady()
    {
        while (!Advertisement.IsReady(bannerPlacementId))
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }

        Advertisement.Banner.Show(bannerPlacementId);
    }

    public void HideBanner()
    {
        Advertisement.Banner.Hide(false);
    }

    #endregion
}
```